# h:selectOneRadio doesn't set needed value

Tags: jsf

I have same code sample:

```
<h:selectOneRadio class="answers" id="radioAnswer" value="#{answers.check}" 
    onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this)" rendered="#{main.questionType == 'SINGLE'}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="#{answers.ansValue}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

But when I tried to submit it, it threw this:

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.ELException:
/.xhtml @56,92 value="#{answers.check}": Can't set property 'check' on
class '...' to value 'null'.
```

`answer.check` has boolean type.
It stoped to work correctly after migration from Tomcat 7.x to WebLogic 12c.

Comment: Change `itemValue="true"` to `itemValue="#{true}"` for get a `boolean` result. Also, maybe you could change the attribute from `boolean` to `Boolean`.

Comment: `itemValue="#{true}"` didn't help. Change `bolean` on `Boolean` I tried before but it didn't set `answers.check` too and threw `NullPointerException`.